# Is it possible to transfer information displayed in putty to my local computer?

Tags: putty

I am using putty to remotely access a Unix machine and would like to somehow record the output to my local machine. Are there any techniques to allow this? For example if I perform a grep on a file, I would like the output to be displayed in my putty session, but also stored locally on my PC.

I am aware that Putty has the feature "Copy all to Clipboard" but sometimes the output produced is longer than the screen, so "Copy all to Clipboard" only gets the end of the output.

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found it! There is a logging section in the Putty configuration. This can write all session data to a local log file and does exactly what I need.